# The XPage doesn't see the resource (jss library) from my Theme

Tags: themes, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have created a Theme and switced on it in the Application properties.
I have also included a jss library in it:

```
<resources>
 <script target="xsp" src="/TEST.jss"clientSide="false" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
</resources>
```

So, when the XPage is launched the error message is thrown of that there can not be found a function from this jss library. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way "officialy" to include a SSJS Library in a theme.  There is a hacky way noted here: http://www.iqjam.net/iqjam/iqjam.nsf/questionread.xsp?documentId=144ED5F29CB7031F802576E7005732B2&action=openDocument&SessionID=DD0UUYQPUX

I have copied the code in case the link dies in future.  As with a lot of good things in the xpages community, this code is courtesy of Tim Tripcony.  There are a number of caveats regarding when the SSJS can be used; these are available in the comments at the link above.

```
<control>
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>#{javascript:var    ssjsLibrary:com.ibm.xsp.resource.ScriptResource = new   com.ibm.xsp.resource.ScriptResource();
ssjsLibrary.setClientSide(false);
ssjsLibrary.setSrc("/experiment.jss");
this.addResource(ssjsLibrary);
return "";}</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Comment: It's officially said in the book "Mastering Xpages": "This element (<resources>) is a container for several different types of rersources. Unlike the <resource> element, both client-side and server-side resources can be specified. The <resources> element is more powerful than its <resource> ancestor, and should be used in preference to it"

Comment: @Dexter it seems my info is out of date.  Paul's answer is the more up to date one.

Comment: Yes, it can be used in a theme. I created a repository on GitHub to allow you to add a DTD definition to your theme to get content assist https://github.com/paulswithers/xpages_theme_dtd. See the readme for info. The caveat is you need to remove those three lines before testing on the server, or the theme cannot be parsed successfully.
Any updates, let me know so I can add to the DTD :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to reference the function?

The theme is only applied during the Render Response phase, so specifying the SSJS library in the theme means it will not be available for `beforePageLoad` or `afterPageLoad` events. To use in those events, add the SSJS library in a layout custom control, which will be used on all pages.

Comment: I am using it on the "Data" bookmark on the XPage. The function is used in "Search in view results" of the View data resource

Comment: Data source properties probably get calculated during the page load or when initialising the components. Try adding some kind of log / debug statement in beforePageLoad, afterPageLoad, beforeRenderResponse and afterRenderResponse to see if the error is occurring earlier than the Render Response Phase. If it is, you won't be able to use the theme.

Comment: Yes, it's true - Data source properties are initialized when initialising the components - according to log\debug statement. The "problem" function is invoked between BeforePageLoad and AfterPageLoad events on the Page. So, as I can see, the Theme is loaded after all components on the Page?

Comment: Correct, it's only applied during Render Response. This is why it's more efficient if you're computing properties, because the calculation will only be computed once during a partial refresh.